# BigQuery - Get extra rows between 2 identical tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two table with the exact same structure but one table has extra lines and I would like to figure out what are those lines. This is what I tried to query but seems the minus operator does not work on BQ. What should I do?

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE (date = '2021-01-31')
MINUS
SELECT *
FROM `table2`
WHERE (date = '2021-01-31')
```

example of result (around 15 columns). I just want to get the lines that are present in table1 but not in table2.

```
campaign date conversions ....
a 2021-01-31 8374474
b 2021-01-31 948383
c 2021-01-31 3948484
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EXCEPT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except) to get exactly this - see example below

```
select * from _temp_b
except distinct 
select * from _temp_a
```

If to apply it to sample data from Daniel's answer  - output is obviously the same but with literally zero coding

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the below.  This would really depend on you being able to define a unique row identifier (or a hash of the row) and join the two tables together on that column(s) where the table with fewer rows returns a null value.

```
with _temp_a as (
    select 'a' campaign, '2021-01-31' date, 8374474 conversions union all
    select 'b' campaign, '2021-01-31' date, 948383 conversions
),
_temp_b as (
    select 'a' campaign, '2021-01-31' date, 8374474 conversions union all
    select 'b' campaign, '2021-01-31' date, 948383 conversions union all
    select 'c' campaign, '2021-01-31' date, 3948484 conversions
)

select b.*
from _temp_b b 
left join _temp_a a
 on b.campaign =a.campaign 
 and b.date = a.date 
where a.campaign is null
```